# App Widget gone after App update from store

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an app with a Widget. Everytime I upload an update to the store and the app updates on the mobile device, the Widget is gone. Same when Debugging from the PC. What do I miss? I guess this is a common issue...

Comment: put your Widget code from manifest

Answer (score 0):

- Move apps to internal storage, the update process will be faster reducing the chance of being affected

  - Use a third-party launcher, most appear to have implemented a workaround.
  - Disable affected apps auto-update.

Answer (score 0):

Not suer, is it common behavior, but you can request to put widget of your application, when app updates.

Listen app updates throw Broadcasting.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.your.receiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                    <data android:scheme="package"/> 
                </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
```

Requesting Widget picker.

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetID);
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, KEY_CODE);
```